# The sum of a completely continuous function with a contraction is a condensing function?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X=(X,|\cdot|)$ be a Banach space and let $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2:B_r[0,X] \longrightarrow X$ such that $\Gamma_1$ is completely continuous and $\Gamma_2$ is a contraction. Under these conditions, $\Gamma_1+\Gamma_2$ is a condensing map?

Where, $B_r[0,X]$ denote de closed ball, of radius $r>0$, center $0 \in X$, in $X$.

That's true? I conjectured this, however I can not prove nor give a counterexample.

Comment: What is a condensing map?

Comment: And what is a completely continuous map on a ball?  'completely continuous' is  a term generally used for a compact operator.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy map the ball in a relatively compact set.